# grep and output pattern after match string

Tags: string, perl, awk, sed, grep

I have two files where the strings in file1 matches part of the string in file 1.

**Question1:**
How do I output the part AFTER the match?

file1:

```
 TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTT
 TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTT
 ACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATA
```

file2:

```
CGCTCCGTTCTCTTTTGCCTGATTCCAGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAGTTTGAGGGTCTATGATACCACCCGGTACAGGAGATAA
GTCCGCCGGCTCCCACACCATGGCCCTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTGGTCGGGTTGTGACATT
TTGTGCACACTGAACCTACCTGCTTGGGACACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATATGAAC
```

output:

```
 TTGCCTGATTCCAGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAG
 CACACCATGGCCCTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTG
 CCTGCTTGGGACACATACTTCTTTATATGCCC
```

**Question2:**
How do I output the part BEFORE the match?

file1:

```
GCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAG
CTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCT
TTATATGCCC
```

file2:

```
CGCTCCGTTCTCTTTTGCCTGATTCCAGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTACAG
GTCCGCCGGCTCCCACACCATGGCCCTGGCTGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTG
TTGTGCACACTGAACCTACCTGCTTGGGACACATACTTCTTTATATGCCC
```

output:

```
CGCTCCGTTCTCTTTTGCCTGATTCCAG
GTCCGCCGGCTCCCACACCATGGCCCTGG
TTGTGCACACTGAACCTACCTGCTTGGGACACATACTTCT
```

grep -A would also work if I had only one pattern. However I have multiple pattern (file1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part before the match:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {split($0,b,a[FNR]); print b[1]}' file1 file2
```

For the part after:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {split($0,b,a[FNR]); print b[2]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: What if I want to output the part BEFORE the match?

Comment: Update your question to show some sample input and expected output of your complete question. Don't dole it out piecemeal or you'll probably end up with a worse solution than if we knew what you wanted up front.

Comment: In the first one - do you REALLY want the spaces at the front of the output or do you not care?

Comment: No, i don't whant the spaces.

Comment: OK, thats a VERY different question with a much simpler solution. It's very important to post accurate input/output. I'll update my answer.

Comment: there seem to be a bug somewhere. It workes for the first 30 lines. Do you mind me sending over the true files?

Comment: I won't look at anything other than what's posted on this site.